# Python assertIn test statement not finding string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `assertIn` to test that a part of the result in JSON string is correct.

```
test_json = some_function_returning_a_dict()
self.assertIn(expected_json, test_json, "did not match expected output")
```

The error is

> AssertionError: "'abc': '1.0012'," not found in [{'abc': '1.0012',...

I used `Ctrl + F` over the inner string, and it was in the resulting string.
 I'm using Python 3.0

Comment: A dict is not a JSON string, and testing for the presence of a substring would be a horrible way to validate a JSON string anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right.  Python's **in** operator works on an iterable object.  The clause **in test_json** means, "is the given item a key of the dictionary".  It does *not* search the dictionary for a *key:value* pair.

To do this, use a two-step process:

```
assertIn('abc', test_json)
assertEquals('1.0012', test_json['abc'])
```

Doing this with appropriate variables and references is left as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Comment: Or you could use the `items()` view.

Comment: Right.  I left most of the solution to the "student".

Answer (score 1):

`"'abc': '1.0012',"` is a string and `{'abc': '1.0012', }` is an entry in dictionary

You want to be checking for the dictionary entry in json, not a string

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to find a string inside a dictionary, which will check to see if the string you are giving is a key of the specified dictionary. Firstly don't convert your first dictionary to a string, and secondly do something like `all(item in test_json.items() for item in expected_json.items())`